# Cómo hago un formulario con react-hook-form para obtener los valores en un objeto?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, frontend, react-hook-form

Estoy implementando un sistema de encuestas que emplea reactjs y react-hook-form para el trabajo con formularios, necesito crear un formulario que recoja la pregunta y sus respectivas respuestas. Como mínimo el usuario podrá insertar dos respuestas, y no tendrá tope para el máximo, estas respuestas cuando sean más de dos el usuario las podrá agregar de forma dinámica, y en igual caso, podrá eliminar los input que no desee, exceptuando los 2 que son por defecto.

Cómo puedo hacer para obtener los datos del formulario en el formato que espera la base de daros?
Cómo puedo hacer para que al momento de eliminar el campo de forma dinámica me elimine el que se seleccionó, y no el último que se creaó?
Comó garantizar que no existan input vacios al momento del envío al backend? Es decir si el input 1 tiene valores, lo agrego, si el 2 tiene valores, lo agrego, si el 3 no tiene valores, lo salto, si el 4 tiene valortes lo agrego...

**La base de datos espera (MongoDB):**

```
{
    "pregunta": "¿Pregunta 1?",
    "opciones": [
        {
            "opcion": "Opción 1",
            "votos": 0
        },
        {
            "opcion": "Opción 2",
            "votos": 0
        },
        {
            "opcion": "Opción 3",
            "votos": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

**En el frontend tengo:**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useInquests } from "../../context/inquestContext";

function InquestFormPage() {
  const [optionList, setOptionList] = useState([
    { option: "" },
    { option: "" }
  ]);
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const { createInquest } = useInquests();

  const handleOptionChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...optionList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setOptionList(list);
  };

  const handleOptionRemove = (index) => {
    const list = [...optionList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setOptionList(list);
  };

  const handleOptionAdd = () => {
    setOptionList([...optionList, { option: "" }]);
  };

  const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
    // createInquest(data);
    console.log(data);
  });

  return (
    <div className="flex h-[calc(100vh-100px)] justify-center items-center">
      <div className="bg-zinc-800 max-w-md p-10 w-full rounded-md">

        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Encuesta</h1>

        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} autoComplete="false">

          <input type="text" {...register('pregunta', { required: true, min: 10 })}
            className="w-full bg-zinc-700 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md my-2"
            placeholder="Pregunta" autoFocus
          />

          {optionList.map((singleOption, index) => (

            <div className="flex justify-between items-center my-2" key={index}>
              <input type="text" id={`respuesta_${index + 1}`} {...register(`respuesta_${index + 1}`, { required: true, min: 2 })}
                className="w-full bg-zinc-700 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md"
                placeholder={`Opción ${index + 1}`}
              />
              {optionList.length !== 2 && (
                <button type="button" onClick={() => handleOptionRemove(index)} className="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold rounded py-2 px-4 ml-2">-</button>
              )}
            </div>

          ))}

          <div className="flex justify-between items-center my-2">

            <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold rounded py-2 px-4 my-2">Enviar</button>

            <button type="button" onClick={handleOptionAdd} className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold rounded py-2 px-4 my-2">+</button>

          </div>

        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default InquestFormPage
```